# PHP Copy Dynamically created TIFF image from remote server

Tags: php, image, dynamic, curl, tiff

I've written a script that searches through exiting legal case dockets for things like "motion to intervene" and "motion to compel". If the regular expression returns true, then it looks to see if there is a scanned image of the document online for public use. That image is a TIFF file, but not an ordinary tiff file. Here is a link to an example of what I'm trying to copy to my own server.

http://www.oscn.net/applications/oscn/getimage.tif?submitted=true&casemasterid=2565129&db=OKLAHOMA&barcode=1012443256

Here is the error you get if you only try to look at the http://www.oscn.net/applications/oscn/getimage.tif

It is a TIFF file but dynamic. I've used the fopen(), CURL, etc without success. I've used these types of functions with JPG images from random sites just to check to make sure that my server allowed this type of stuff and it worked.

I don't have PDFlib installed on the server (I checked the PEAR and it's not available there either, though I'm not 100% sure that is where it would be.) My host uses cPanel. The server is running Apache. I'm not sure where else to look for a solution to this problem.

I've seen some solutions that used PDFlib but each of those grabbed a normal TIFF image, not one that was dynamically created. My thought though is that it shouldn't matter if I can get the image data to stream, shouldn't I be able to use fopen() and write or buffer that data into my own .tif file?

Thanks for any input and Happy Thanksgiving!

UPDATE: The issue wasn't with CURL, it was with the URL I scraped to pass to CURL. When I printed the $url to the screen, it looked right, but it wasn't. Somewhere & was turned into &, which then threw off CURL because it was fetching an invalid URL (invalid at least according to the remote server where the TIF file is).

For those of you finding this later, here is the script that works perfectly.

```
//*******************************************************************************
$url = 'http://www.oscn.net/applications/oscn/getimage.tif"
$url .= '?submitted=true&casemasterid=2565129&db=OKLAHOMA&barcode=1016063497';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // get the transfer as a string, rather than output it directly

print "Attempting to fetch file...\n";
$img = curl_exec($ch); // get the image

//I used the time() so that in testing I would know when a new file was created rather than always overwriting the old file. This will be changed for final version
if($img){
  $fh = fopen('oscn_docs/' . time(). '.tif', 'w'); // this will simply overwrite the file. If that's not what you want to do, you'll have to change the 'w' argument!
  if($fh){
    $byteswritten = fwrite($fh, $img);
    fclose($fh);
  }else{
    print "Unable to open file.\n";
  }
}else{
  print "Unable to fetch file.\n";
}

print "Done.\n";
exit(0);
//*******************************************************************************
```

jarod

Comment: You say you've used fopen, CURL, etc without success? Why exactly did these fail? What error(s)/problem(s) did you encoundter?

Comment: I'd be interested in the results of those attempts as well.  I'm not aware of any reason why a dynamic image would matter, unless perhaps the host has some scripting in place to prevent hotlinking or scraping of the documents, which is entirely possible.

Comment: I asked a friend who helped me get it working and then I was able to figure out why my script wasn't working. The issue was WAY simpler than the CURL script. I scraped the URL to pass to CURL so it could open the TIF image. I printed the URL and it looked correct I used strlen() on each only to find that they were not equal. I found that the & in the scraped url had been turned into &amp; so I used string replace and turned &amp; back into just & and it works perfectly now.

Hope this helps others. Thanks

Comment: How do I respond to my own question not in a comment like this?

Comment: For any of us who read through old questions - and those that may stumble across them while searching for specific solutions, then it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question (if you've found a solution) in the off-chance it may benefit someone else.  If you accept your own answer it then "checks it off" so that it won't appear in the *unanswered* section :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you finding this later, here is the script that works perfectly.

```
//*******************************************************************************
$url = 'http://www.oscn.net/applications/oscn/getimage.tif"
$url .= '?submitted=true&casemasterid=2565129&db=OKLAHOMA&barcode=1016063497';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // get the transfer as a string, rather than output it directly

print "Attempting to fetch file...\n";
$img = curl_exec($ch); // get the image

//I used the time() so that in testing I would know when a new file was created rather than always overwriting the old file. This will be changed for final version
if($img){
  $fh = fopen('oscn_docs/' . time(). '.tif', 'w'); // this will simply overwrite the file. If that's not what you want to do, you'll have to change the 'w' argument!
  if($fh){
    $byteswritten = fwrite($fh, $img);
    fclose($fh);
  }else{
    print "Unable to open file.\n";
  }
}else{
  print "Unable to fetch file.\n";
}

print "Done.\n";
exit(0);
//*******************************************************************************
```